# Proving differentiability of a payoff

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, malliavin-calculus

Let $F = \Phi (X^x_T)$. $X^x_T$ behaves as a risky asset such that $dX^x_t=rX^x_tdt+\sigma X^x_tdW_t$ with $W_t$ standard Brownian Motion; $X_0^x=x$. $\Phi$ is continuous with linear growth and $P(x) = e^{−rT}\mathbb{E}[F]$. Prove that $P \in C^2(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R}) $.

I've already proved that $P \in C^1(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R}$). Also, solving the SDE, we obtain $X^x_T=x e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T+\sigma \sqrt{T}Y}$ with $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ but I have no idea on how to continue. Could some one help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, actually I'm kind of lost. I thought to prove at least that it is twice differentiable by doing something like $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} E[F] = \frac{d}{dx} E[\frac{d}{dx}F]$ and taking the expectation as an integral and using later the fact that $\Phi$ has linear growth,  but this I see it doesn't lead anywhere as we don't have the security of the existence of the derivative of $\Phi$.

Comment: Hello, actually this is question from a problem set given in class, so unfortunately I can't give you any reference, also, the original question is written like this. Sorry I can't help you in this sense.

Comment: OP: how tid you prove that $P\in C^1\,?$ @ThomasKojar: Even for a discontinuous $\Phi$ the expectation $\mathbb E[\Phi(X^x_T)]$ can be infinitely often differentiable.
Example: $\Phi(x)=1_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$ by which $\mathbb E[\Phi(X^x_T)]=N(d_1)$ with
$$d_1=\frac{\ln(x/K)+rT-\sigma^2T/2)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}\,.$$

Comment: Hi, I proved $C^1$ by taking the expectation as an integral, therefore we have the integral of a product of continuous functions (which is continuous) and by the fundamental theorem of calculus you get that this integral es $C^1$, therefore $E[F]$ is $C^1$

Answer (score 1):

This is shown in Le Gall [Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-31089-3)
 theorem 7 (for continuous and bounded but the proof is similar). Another source is here [lecture 12: stochastic differential equations, diffusion](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/391/Lecture12.pdf):

Define the infinitesimal generator of the process $X_{t}$ to be the differential generator

$$G=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)\partial_{xx}+\mu(x)\partial_{x}.$$

> **Theorem 5** Assume that $\mu(x),\sigma(x)$ are Lipschitz with linear growth. Let $f(x),K(x)$ be continuous such that $K\geq 0$ and $f(x)=O(|x|)$ as $|x|\to +\infty$. Then the function defined by
> $$u(t,x)=E_{x}\left[exp(-\int_{0}^{t}K(X_{s})ds)f(X_{t})\right]$$
> satisfies the diffusion equation $u_{t}=Gu-Ku$ with $u(0,x)=f(x)$.

As mentioned there one needs to make a modification for unbounded. In particular, we need integrability but thanks to the linear growth we have

$$E[\Phi(X_{t}^{x})]\leq cE[|X_{t}^{x}|]=cE[X_{t}^{x}]=cxe^{rT}<\infty.$$

The rest of the proof is the same as in the case of $f$ being bounded and continuous.

Comment: if you have any feedback, I will gladly to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But actually I'm a little bit lost with your proof. With this you are just proving that $P(x)$ is $C^1$, no? How do you prove that it is indeed $C^2$.

Comment: @ManuelPerez the G-operator contains a double derivative